# Can you place a link or button inside MDB accordion?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I have a button inside the accordion headings (that serve as buttons to open/close the accordion item).

When I click on the button, the underlying method gets called, but also the accordion opens/closes.

Can you somehow disable the accordion functionality for a specific button inside?

Example:

[MDB Editor](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/anonymer_boi/2786315)

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          
          <a href="javascript:alert('hi')" class="ml-4">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
          
          <a href="javascript:alert('hi')" class="ml-4">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
          
          <a href="javascript:alert('hi')" class="ml-4">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to disable? The test link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you wish to NOT have the accordion functionality on the "test" link... But still want the functionnality on rest of the button.

So for that link, you will need:

- [e.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the click event from bubbling up to the button
- [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the normal anchor behavior

Then, I suggest you to use one event handler tied to a class, instead of some inline JS. In my example, you can see how to determine which link was clicked and apply some specific action then.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".test").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
  
    clickedHeader = e.target.closest(".card-header").id
    alert("Test link in #"+clickedHeader)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          
          <a href="#" class="ml-4 test">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
          
          <a href="#" class="ml-4 test">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
          
          <a href="#" class="ml-4 test">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
I have removed `data-target="#collapseTwo"` to `data-target="#"`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').click(function(){
    alert('I am Working!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="#" data-target="#collapseOne"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          
          <a href="javascript:alert('hi')" class="ml-4">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
      data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed test" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
          
          <a href="javascript:alert('hi')" class="ml-4">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card z-depth-0 bordered">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
          
          <a href="javascript:alert('hi')" class="ml-4">Test</a>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
        wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum
        eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla
        assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
        nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
        farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
        labore sustainable.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```